# Any alternative to NSURL?

Tags: ios, nsurl

A client is pondering development of an iPhone and iPad app and has asked an odd question: Is there any way to send data from an iOS device to a server other than using NSURL?

Comment: Why does NSURL not meet your needs?

Comment: are you sure you mean NSURL? Do you mean NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, are you referring the whole NSURLConnection style connections? if so there is ASIHttpRequest, if you are just referring to NSURL then I am with highlycaffeinated, explain why NSURL does not work for you and we will be able to provide you a quality answer.

Comment: I love when questions try to make it seem like someone else is asking ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using a POST request

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/your/servlet"]];

NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"foo=bar&key=value"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

That way the data would go inside the body of the request and not on the URL itself

Answer (score 0):

The **NSURL** API isn't a way of getting data from a server.  It's just a class for storing a URL.  I suppose if you *really* want to avoid NSURL as much as possible, you could store URLs in an **NSString**, and then use appropriate APIs to convert it into an NSURL right before you use it.

To get data from a server, you would use either the NSURLSession API (modern) or NSURLConnection API (kind of crufty).  Either is a fairly straightforward way to fetch data from an HTTP or HTTPS URL.

If you don't want to use either of those URL fetching APIs for some reason, you can write your own code using sockets or grab libcurl (MIT license) and link it into your app.  Be aware that if you write your own socket code or use libcurl, assuming you're writing code for iOS, you'll need to occasionally use high-level APIs such as NSURL or CFHost to wake up the cellular radio.